# How to compile Qt examples?

Tags: qt

I built Qt 5.7 from sources with VS2015 (according this article: http://developernote.com/2016/06/how-to-compile-qt-5-7-with-vs2015/), looks like the build succeeded, but I cannot find compiled examples (*.exe files of examples). What I did wrong?
I thought that 'example' target:

```
configure -debug -nomake examples -opensource
```

means compile Qt+examples, isn't it?

Comment: It means compile without examples :)

Comment: compiled examples with configure -debug -opensource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to change `-nomake` to `-make`, as you are excluding the examples this way.